# How to create Single .tar file with multiple tar file

Tags: java, tar

I have multiple tar file eg:- `201704132343-folderpath1.tar` , `201704212300-folderpath2.tar`. 
I have to create single tar file which should include all tar files. I must follow tar path so I can restore all files in respected folder.
 First I am taking backup of all files from different directory like `/2017/04/13/23/43/CustomerData` 
 `/2017/04/21/23/00/CountryData` and I am creating tar file with path name, So I can restore all files in respected folders. 
But I have to give single tar file. Folder path is dynamic based on date . Is my design is wrong ? Is it possible to making single tar file with multiple tar file? 
I have to do it in java

Comment: And you want do this in java?

Comment: I thought the platform will be Linux...

Comment: Are you sure that you want pack multiple tar files and not multiple tar.gz files?  If this is for java, post the code. Otherwise edit your question or move it to the right platform.

Comment: Yes I want do it in java

Answer (score 1):

Let me recap your requirements.

1. You need to deliver a single tar file.
2. You need to be able to restore individual directories.
3. You don't **need** to create the initial tar files separately ... but that is what you are doing.

If this is correct, the solution is simple.  Don't create a tar file for the individual directories.  Create a single file for everything.  You can always restore individuals, directories, and even subtrees from a single tar file containing everything.

If you do need to create the tar files separately, then it is possible to concatenate a pair of tar files using `tar -A`, or add files / directories using `tar -u`.  However, if you intend to do this, you need to include the directory paths ... otherwise you will get naming collisions.

It is also possible to put tar files inside tar files.  Put if you do that extraction is a two-stage process: 1) extract the inner tar from the outer tar and 2) extract the files from the inner tar.